# Set a default value to a property

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to set a default value without the body of a property? Preferably with annotations.

```
[SetTheDefaultValueTo(true)]
public bool IsTrue { get; set; }

[SetTheDefaultValueTo(false)]
public bool IsFalse { get; set; }

public void Something()
{
    var isTrue = this.IsTrue;
    var isFalse = this.IsFalse;
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to set the value of a property with metadata.  You could use a factory of some sort that would build instances of a class with reflection and then that could set the default values.  But in short, you need to use the constructors (or field setters, which are lifted to the constructor) to set the default values.

If you have several overloads for your constructor, you may want to look at [constructor chaining](http://www.csharp411.com/constructor-chaining/).

Using C# 6+, you are able to do something like this...

```
public string MyValue { get; set; } = "My Default";
```

Oh, it gets more fun because people have even requested something like this...

```
// this code won't compile!
public string MyValue {
    private string _myValue;
    get { return _myValue ?? "My Default"; }
    set { _myValue = value; }
}
```

... the advantage being that you could control the scope of the field to only be accesible in the property code so you don't have to worry about anything else in your class playing with the state without using the getter/setter.

Comment: Is there a place where I can vote for this feature or something like that?

Comment: You may be able to find something on connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: eek... I just found this on CodeProject.  It uses reflection to set the default values after the object has been constructed. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AutoPropsDefaultValues.aspx

Comment: I thought I saw another entry somewhere on this site for a link to a report on connect.microsoft.com... I have not been able to find it again.  If someone finds the link I would gladly update my answer to include it.

Comment: Very confusing--I though your second code example was being offered as a solution, not as an example of something that doesn't work. I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 16):

Assign the default property value in the class constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        IsTrue = true;
        IsFalse = false;
    }

    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }

    public bool IsFalse { get; set; }

    [...]

    public void Something()
    {
        var isTrue = this.IsTrue;
        var isFalse = this.IsFalse;
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks more like his question instead of an answer to it.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using C#5 and earlier, you have to do it in a constructor.

but since C# 6.0, the ability to have auto property initializers is included, and the syntax is:

```
public int myage { get; set; } = 33;
```

Answer (score 9):

Old thread. 
Looks like Microsoft heard and this feature is available in .Net Framework 4.6+ (C# 6+) 
You can use it like

```
public string MyValue { get; set; } = "My Default";
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer rather than Chitioui, as his answer was 2 months later and it added nothing to this.

Answer (score 1):

In this very specific example, you sort of can:

```
public bool IsFalse { get; set; }
public bool IsTrue
{
    get { return !IsFalse; }
    set { IsFalse = !value; }
}

public void Something()
{
    var isTrue = this.IsTrue;
    var isFalse = this.IsFalse;
}
```

But, in general, no.