# C#: How to set default values of properties

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value)

Hi all:

If I want to add default value, says 60, to following property for a class, what is the most convenient way in C#3.0

```
public int someSetting { get; set; }
```

Comment: duplicate of at least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071359/set-a-default-value-to-a-property , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value and probably many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the best way is to set the default in the constructor of the class

Answer (score 4):

Put it in the parameterless constructor, that's what I'd do.

**Edit:** Yes, I guess what I mean by the above is any constructor where the parameter in question is not passed in.

Comment: And if another constructor has been used?

Comment: @Oded: Nested constructors call probably

Comment: @abatishchev - big assumption. I have seem many cases where constructors were not chained.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize it in all constructors.